# Show/Hide LWC Design attributes based on the value of another design attribute on builder page Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an App builder page and I am using Design attributes to pass on values from Lightning page to LWC component. However, Is there is any way that I can show/hide my Design attribute field on app builder page based on the value selected in other Design Property?

For e.g - I have a picklist property (Picklist Field1) on app builder and I want to show another text or pickList property on app builder page based on value which is selected in Picklist Field1. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible today, but there's an [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CTa2QAG) you can vote on.